# How to label group of ticks?

Tags: plotting, matrix, graphics3d, labeling, ticks

I am plotting a matrix in 3D and what I did so far is this:

[image]

So, what I would like to do now is to add different labels to group of ticks, in this way:

[image]

Even only on the bottom axis is perfect.

The code that I am using is this one:

```
iF = Interpolation[Join@@MapIndexed[Composition[Reverse, List], *list*,{2}]];`

plot3DmW = DiscretePlot3D[iF[i, j], {i, 1, Dimensions[*list*][[1]]}, {j, 1, 
Dimensions[*list*][[2]]}, ExtentSize -> Full,FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap",Axes -> True,Ticks -> {{{1, "-6,L"}, 
{2, "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, {4, "7,R"}}, {{1,"-6,L"}, {2, "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, 
{4,"7,R"}}, {0, 1}},AxesLabel -> {None, None, "Probability"},LabelStyle -> 
Directive[Black, Bold, Medium],PlotLegends -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {4, 10, 10}]
```

I hope you can help me and teach me more!

Comment: Solved! The changes have been made only in the Ticks, so I leave here only that part that solve the problem:

`Ticks -> {{{1, "-6,L"}, {1.3, Style["\nB", Bold, 16]}, , {2, 
    "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, {3.25, Style["\nA", Bold, 16]}, {4, 
    "7,R"}}, {{1, "-6,L"}, {2, "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, {4, "7,R"}}, {0, 
   1}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The changes have been made only in the Ticks, so I leave here only that part that solve the problem:

```
Ticks -> {{{1, "-6,L"}, {1.3, Style["\nB", Bold, 16]}, , {2, "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, {3.25, Style["\nA", Bold, 16]}, {4, "7,R"}}, {{1, "-6,L"}, {2, "6,R"}, {3, "-7,L"}, {4, "7,R"}}, {0, 1}}
```